# Batch file to create events based on found text

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that creates one  event if a text string is found and another if the string is not found. What I have so far is:

```
rem ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rem *  If the log file contains the 'copied' word log an event
rem ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

find /c "copied" C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log\backup.log
if errorlevel 1 goto ONE
if errorlevel 0 goto ZERO

:ZERO
eventcreate /L Application /T Information  /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 900 /D "Copied in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
goto END

:ONE
eventcreate /L Application /T Error  /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 901 /D "Error in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
:END
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong because it either always reports success even when I tell the script to look for a nonsense text or it reports failure when the correct text is present.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
rem ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rem *  If the log file contains the 'copied' word log an event
rem ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /c "copied" "C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log\backup.log"
if errorlevel 1 goto NotFound

%SystemRoot%\System32\eventcreate.exe /L Application /T Information /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 900 /D "Copied in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
goto :EOF

:NotFound
%SystemRoot%\System32\eventcreate.exe /L Application /T Error /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 901 /D "Error in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
```

The name of the log file as well as its path contains spaces. Therefore you must enclose the log file name with path in double quotes.

See also Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

The condition `if errorlevel 0` is nearly always true as it means greater or equal 0 and nearly no application exits with a negative return value.

Answer (score 0):

This is another method.

Your error was that the log file path\name needed double quotes around it.

```
find /c "copied" < "C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log\backup.log"

if not errorlevel 1 (
eventcreate /L Application /T Information  /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 900 /D "Copied in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
 ) else (
eventcreate /L Application /T Error  /SO "BackUp Service" /ID 901 /D "Error in backing up files to the back-up store. For more details look in C:\Richards Folders\backup service\create events and logs\test backup log."
)
```